# Citrix display wpf transparent layout control as blue background

Tags: wpf, citrix

Citrix display wpf transparent layout control as blue background.
Any idea how to overcome this problem?

some details:
We publish WPF Application on Citrix XenApp 6.0, Citrix running on Windows server 2008 R2 SP1 64 bit[image]

Answer (score 0):

I overcome this problem by changing the design.  Instated of WPF layout control, we display those lines you see in screen shot,  by showing windows (each line) with no transparent area, the size of the window is determine by its content.
But one that published on Citrix WPF application that have a layout control with transparent area will encounter blue background on it. Solution to avoid it is to generate WPF layout with size according to received content.